# Jenkins log keeps telling me tf eula not accepted but it's not

Tags: macos, tfs, jenkins

I'm try to setup my CI environment on my MacBook Pro with Jenkins. And my source code was in TFS(team foundation system), my MBP can't added in windows domain, because of some restrictions.

1. I've downloaded the TEE command line client on my MBP
2. I've added my TEE path to system path.
3. I've ran "tf eula" in terminal with both logged in local user and sudo
4. I've installed TFS plugin with jenkins.
5. All configuration set with TFS plugin.

After I configured a project with Jenkins job, and start build. Job failed, with error message that reminds me needs to ran "tf eula" accept the EULA first.

But if I ran the command which Jenkins just ran directly in terminal, everything went well, I've successfully connected to TFS server.

I've no idea why this phenomena happened. Would that because jenkins triggered the command with my domain user name? Which my jenkins error log, the first line indicates job was running under my current logged on local user account.

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins usually runs with it's own user. You need to logon as Jenkins user before executing that command

`sudo su jenkins`

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. But the weird thing was: I use LDAP logon jenkins with my local user account. But after Jenkins was on, I found one user account named "Jenkins" in my user switch panel. I've no idea what was the password for this user account. Of cause I also can't find this user under Users&Group system panel. How can I logon as Jenkins user before executing the command?